# Term for a subset $B$ of poset $A$ such that $\forall b \in B,\forall a\in A: a<b\Rightarrow a\in B$

Tags: terminology, order-theory

Suppose that $A$ is a poset, and $B\subseteq A$ such that:

$$\forall b \in B,\forall a\in A: a<b\Rightarrow a\in B$$

This set has a special name. I studied properties of this set in my class, but we called it in a really weird name. I can’t find the name of the set in English. Can someone tell me what is the name of the set in English?

Thanks.

Comment: Such a subset is called an '*ideal*' or 'downset' (or 'downwards closed set') of the poset.

Comment: Though be aware that if the poset also happens to be a lattice (or even just an upper semilattice) then the term "ideal" could also be interpreted to require that $B$ is closed under $\vee$ as well as being downward closed.

Comment: To avoid confusion with the lattice-theoretic notion of ideals, some people say "order-ideal" for "downset".

Comment: It is called a lower set.

Comment: @Berci.  An order ideal is an upward directed, lower set.